# How to generate a partial board solution for N-Queens (P vs NP)?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, np-complete

On Aug 31st 2017. Clay Math Institute and St. Andrews have released an N-Queens Completion $1m challenge.

If the Chess Board size is NxN. and M

I have written the completion algorithm which is of the O(N * (N-M)^2 * Parallelization Constant)

The problem I'm facing is not with the algorithm per se. We consider that more or less proven i.e. P = NP, Polynomial Time.

But everytime I use some adhoc algorithm to place M queens on a NxN partial Board. The completion algorithm rejects it "Inconsistent partial board" and aborts.

The challenge says the algorithm should work on 1024x1024 boards. Which it does. But just because it solves a couple of 1024x1024 adhoc boards doesn't prove anything about the worst case scenario.

For us to claim to the world that we have a solution. We are targeting testing on atleast 1000, 1024x1024 partial boards before making an announcement of the result.

So the question is - How do we generate "randomized" "adhoc" partial NxN boards with M < N queens placed on it. to test the N-Queens completion solution.What set of partial boards will qualify as a good enough test of the solution?

Please let me know, if you need any other details.

Comment: If the Chess Board size is NxN. and M < N queens have already been placed. The completion problem is to place the remaining N-M queens such that (mutual attacks = 0 for each queen)

Comment: Will you be splitting the prize with us if we can help?

Comment: if someone knows the solution, I think he/she will publish the paper instead of revealing it on S/O

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please narrow down your request to constitute an issue that is reproducible and solvable. Actually you're asking for algorithms to randomly set up chess boards, which is too broad.

Comment: Thanks. Will update the question very soon with a more objective and well articulated one.

Comment: In particular you need to state what constitutes an acceptable partial board for a given N to test your algorithm. @AdityaYadav

Comment: Please provide citations for your claims. So far as I know, there is no *new* challenge specifically regarding the n-Queens Completion problem, only the existing [P vs. NP](https://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem) Millennium Challenge. Where do you get the 1024x1024 board size requirement, and what "completion algorithm" is rejecting your initial configurations. It might also be helpful for you to read [this](http://theconversation.com/why-the-worlds-toughest-maths-problems-are-much-harder-than-a-chess-puzzle-and-well-worth-us-1m-83516).

Comment: Paraphrasing from the same article
(1) Finding Solution for N-Queens Completion problem is hard
(2) The algorithm should work for a board of any size. But Clay Institute calculates solving N-Queens Completion for 1000x1000 boards will take a 1000 years so its a good benchmark to test (Para #2) ref- https://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/million-dollar-chess-challenge/

New or not the challenge was announced on 31st Aug 2017 ref: https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/news/archive/2017/title,1539813,en.php

Comment: I know everyone asked me for further inputs on my initial question. And trust me I'm working on it. But I hope time is not a constraint, because I'm constantly working on responses, but its not trivial to articulate, atleast not so quickly. will take time. Please bear with me.

Need less to say I appreciate each and every response to my question.

Comment: @AdityaYadav Please read the update to the St. Andrews link you just posted... "There has been some confusion about the $1m prize offered by the Clay Mathematics Institute in America..." and the clarification from Clay Mathematics Institute. The initial announcement was overly enthusiastic and sloppy in reporting the publication of the paper, which has lead to incorrect assumptions on the part of other news outlets. For example, all of the articles I've seen (including the Digital Trends article you link) refer to the "Queens Problem" rather than "n-Queens" and "n-Queens Completion".

Comment: @breaker Agreed! & Have seen the update. My original question was about the initial input to the "n-Queens Completion" problem which is in accordance with the Updated Notification from Clay Mathematics Institute. Right now I'm reading all research papers 'again' so that I can respond to the questions posed back to me by multiple gentlemen.

Comment: If you still expect an answer I suggest to update this question or else scrap it. @AdityaYadav